# How to access a button in a table via the cell index

Tags: javascript

In a HTML page I have a table with buttons in the cells. Now I want to change the text of the buttons using js. But I can not do it using an id, I need to do that depending on the cell index, like that:

```
document.getElementById.rows[i].cells[j].???? = "Buttontext";
```

I know with:

```
document.getElementById.rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML = "Buttontext";
```

one can change the text in the cell, but I need a similiar function to change the text of the button placed in the cell.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your HTML so that we can see how the buttons relate to the table?

Comment: If it's a HTML5 button like `<button>Test</button` you can do `...cells[j].querySelector('button').innerHTML = "Buttontext"`.

Answer (score 1):

Considering you have only the button inside your cell, you could use:

```
document.getElementById("tableid").rows[i].cells[j].firstChild.innerHTML="buttontext";
```

If you have other elements inside the cell, you can loop through them to find your button. If you have multiple buttons, check for the one you want inside the loop (First button, second button, etc.)

**Example:**

*HTML*

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<table id="tableid">
<tbody>
<tr><td><button>Woho!</button></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

*Javascript*

```
document.getElementById("tableid").rows[0].cells[0].firstChild.innerHTML="buttontext";
```

Aditionally, as suggested by Batu Zet in the comments, if there is only one button but it isn't the first element in the cell and you know it's index, you can use:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].children[indexOfButton].inne‌​rHTML="buttontext";
```

Comment: Good answer. And if it's not the first child you can do : document.getElementById("myTable").rows[i].cells[j].children[indexOfButton].innerHTML="buttontext";

Answer (score 1):

you can find the button inside the rows and cells:

```
document.getElementById('myTable').rows[0].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('button')[0].innerText='New Name';
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mghomoos/

Answer (score 0):

Use [`document.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) like so:

```js
var i = 2,
    j = 3;
document.querySelector("table tr:nth-child("+i+") > td:nth-child("+j+") > button").innerHTML = "ButtonText";
```

```html
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td><button>3</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>4</td><td>5</td><td><button>6</button></td></tr>
    <tr><td>7</td><td>8</td><td><button>9</button></td></tr>
</table>
```

You may find you don't have to be that specific. For example, if there's only one button per row:

```
document.querySelector("table tr:nth-child("+i+") button").innerHTML = "ButtonText";
```